# Can I create a view that combines multiple images from single node with images from other nodes that entity reference the original node?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a content type called "exhibition" that contains *many* images added via the standard image field. I also have a separate content type called "video" that uses an entity reference to point to an "exhibition". Each video node has a *single* image field for a thumbnail.

I want to create a block view that will be displayed on each exhibition's page in a sidebar that combines thumbnails of the exhibition's images with thumbnails of any videos linked to that node. **How can I create this sort of combined view?**

For example:
node/100 is an exhibition containing: image_1.png,image_2.png,image_3.png

node/200 is a video linked to node/100 containing: videothumb_1.png
node/201 is a video linked to node/100 containing: videothumb_2.png

I want a block to display in the sidebar of node/100 that renders the following:

image_1.png,image_2.png,image_3.png,videothumb_1.png,videothumb_2.png

I am experienced enough with Views that I can create a working block that displays image_1.png,image_2.png,image_3.png. I can also easily create a second block using relationships that correctly displays videothumb_1.png,videothumb_2.png. What I would like to do now is combine these separate block views into a single block. My attempts to combine the two seems to always lead to repeated images from the exhibition paired with repeated images from the videos.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't get it to work any other way, you could try using [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to combine the two:

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.